# How to encapsulate text into tags?

Tags: c#, regex, string

Let say we have such string variable:

```
string input = "First regular, <b>bold</b>,<i>italic</i>,<u>underline</u>,<b><i><u>bold+italic+underline</u></i></b>"
```

- string which can contain some html tags in it.

The question is how can i encapsule each "non-taged" text part into some tag, to get smth like this:

```
string output = "<plain>First regular, </plain><b>bold</b><plain>,</plain><i>italic</i><plain>,</plain><u>underline</u><plain>,</plain><b><i><u>bold+italic+underline</u></i></b>"
```

How to do this in C# ? Regex? How should look such regex expression?

Maybe encapsulation isn't good start, what i need is to create xml structure from:

```
 string input = "First regular, <b>bold</b>,<i>italic</i>,<u>underline</u>,<b><i><u>bold+italic+underline</u></i></b>"
```

I need to create

`XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse("<plain>First regular, </plain><b>bold</b><plain>,</plain><i>italic</i><plain>,</plain><u>underline</u><plain>,</plain><b><i><u>bold+italic+underline</u></i></b>")`

Comment: you question is not clear.. and how are you planning to put non tagged content into ANY tag..your both example texts are same .. which tag are u talking about..Is it HTML

Comment: We need more info than that. Now, the first reaction is that you cannot parse xml with regex, but if you're working with a subset of xml, then maybe, juste maybe, we can work something out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: If you need nesting, I would not recommend regex, although .NET's implementation can handle that.

Answer (score 0):

This code is kind of fail, but it should get you on the right path:

```
string input = "First regular, <b>bold</b>,<i>italic</i>,<u>underline</u>,<b><i><u>bold+italic+underline</u></i></b>";
input = "<data>" + input + "</data>";
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.InnerXml = input;
XmlNodeList nodes = xml.SelectNodes("//text()");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) {
    if (node.ParentNode.Name != "b" && node.ParentNode.Name != "i" && node.ParentNode.Name != "u") {
        node.InnerText = "^^^^^" + node.InnerText + "$$$$$";
    }
}
input = xml.DocumentElement.InnerXml.Replace("^^^^^", "<plain>").Replace("$$$$$", "</plain>");
```